# I dropped my Western DIgital Passport 2TB HDD. It shows up in Disk Management but as Not Initialized and Unknown

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mbr

I dropped my Western Digital 2TB HDD Passport from around knee-height. When I reconnected it to my laptop, it showed up with the popup of Safely Remove Hardware. It is visible in Device Manager (as My Passport, with all properties) and in Disk Management (as Disk 1: 1.8TB, Unallocated, Not initialized). Disk management gave me a popup of initializing as MBR or GPT, GPT was selected by default and after finishing that action, I was able to browse and view the files, but after some time windows hung and the laptop restarted after which I was unable to see the drive in File Explorer again. I went ahead and opened Disk Management and it was Unknown, Not initialized this time and when I right-click and select initialize, the GPT option says the drive isn't large enough and MBR says Device error. When I went back to disk management and tried to refresh and then initialize, the initialize option is greyed out. Any help would be appreciated. It would be great if the data is recoverable but even formatting it to reuse the drive would be good.

Comment: If you got it going again would you ever trust it? Trash it & buy a new one.

Comment: And what about the data on it? I presume that if he had backups, he wouldn't be asking

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you don't have backups, or you would not be asking this question (given how cheap drives are, I doubt you care about the physical drive, and, as Tetsujin pointed out in comments, you cn no longer trust that drive. So ...

Lesson learned: always have backups.

You can buy an external drive and use that.

Off-site backup is also useful, in case your house is burgled, or burned down, or you live in Alabama and your house is trashed by a hurricane. You just take another extranet drive round to  a friend's house every few weeks. Personally, I use [BackBlaze](https://www.backblaze.com) which costs about $45/year; it encrypts my data, so that they can't see it, and that $45 covers one PC ***plus external drives*** - I currently back up 7tB.

---

Ok, that's the future dealt with - what about the present?

You need some good disk recovery software.

- you can google for some
- you can ask our sister site Software Recommendations; there are already 45 related questions. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=disk+recovery
- personally, I have had good results with [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva), which has a free and apaid ($19,99) version.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried recuva but it doesn't see the disk at all...

Comment: Hmmm, then I guess you have to keep trying others. try all the free ones first, then look for highly recommends paid solutions. Check computer mag reviews & ask us on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). And start a good backup practise. I hope that you didn't lose anything too valuable

Comment: Yep, I do web dev so these were the offline set of copies, I have a weekly backup of the online files. Some other local files aren't backed up, but nothing too important.

Comment: If the disk cannot be seen then this is hopeless, except for a costly professional service.

Comment: Then I suggest you just bin the drive and get a new one. As per @Tetsujin's comment, "`If you got it going again would you ever trust it?`"

Comment: I disconnected and reconnected the disk and it showed up. Chkdsk said the file system is raw but file explorer shows all files and in the properties window, the file system of the disk is ntfs. I an running Stellar Recovery software and seeing if I can get a backup

Comment: If you are lucky this is just a dislocated connection.